# Does firebase realtime data create a new instance for each user or does everything just get stored in a large tree

Tags: android, database, mobile, firebase

I am new to firebase and Nosql databases. I have gone through the documentations already, but I cannot seem to get my head around a concept.
I have gone through almost every question on here about it, but everyone just seem to conveniently skip the little detail i am looking for.
Suppose I have successfully registered my users using firebaseauth, and can log them in and out, I have my database rules as follows

```
{
"rules": {
"users":{
  "$userid":{
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid == $userid",
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid == $userid"
        }

  }
 }
}
```

Great!, now thats the basic database for a multiuser application. My question is that the users data doesnt get pushed to database from auth automatically, so i have to do a

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mUserRef = mRef.child("users");

    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            String name = "User " + uid.substring(0, 6);

            Userid userid = new Userid(uid);
          mUserRef.push().setValue(userid,  newDatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
```

and so on, on the registeractivity so any userid can have its own node under users where i can post any user specific data. 
I have not implemented this yet, but i forsee that for any read or write data performed by a user will have to search every node to find its own userid, which would take a lot of time when you scale up to like a lot of users and im sure firebase is better than that. So is this how firebase expect us to handle user stuff or does every user just have his own database instance

Comment: you say you will post user specific data under that user's node, why would it `search every node to find its own userid`?

Comment: I was thinking about it all wrong, i think i get it now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `push()` method creates a new, random ID.  This is useful for things like messages in a chat application, but is likely not what you are looking for.

I think you mean to do this:

```
// Get current UID
String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

// Get reference to /users/<uid>
DatabaseReference ref = mUserRef.child(uid);

// Set the value of /users/<uid> to the UserId
Userid userid = new Userid(uid);
ref.setValue(userid);
```

Comment: Oh!, my bad, i think i understand what i need now, thanks

Comment: @hatboysam that means the UID is fixed for each user ? so i can use later to assign more info about each one ??thanks

Comment: Yes you can add more data later, something like ref.child('age').setValue(18)